# How to fix login issue? Flutter - Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

Here is what I'm doing in my code.

```
ReusableButton(
          title: "Login",
          color: Colors.white,
          onPress: () async {
            try {
              final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: myEmailController.text,
                password: myPasswordController.text,
              );
              if (user != null) {
                await Navigator.pushNamed(context, AllTasks.id);
              }
            } catch (e) {
              String newString = e.toString().split("]").removeLast();
              setState(() {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (value) => AlertDialog(
                          title: Text(
                            "Wrong Information",
                            style: kNormalTextStyle,
                          ),
                          content: Text(
                            newString,
                          ),
                          actions: [
                            FlatButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(value).pop();
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  "Close",
                                  style: kNormalTextStyle,
                                ))
                          ],
                        ));
              });
            }
          },
        ),
```

I'm trying to login and after that pushin the page to another page. However this login part is a little bit slow so I get an error like this:

[image]

I'm assuming this is about the connection speed with firebase but is there a solution to solve this? Btw, when I reload the code, it starts working.

Here is my AllTasks code block:

https://github.com/sonelektrikci/task_manager_app_flutter/blob/main/task_management_app_flutter/lib/screens/all_tasks.dart

I'm pushing the page to here when user logs in.

Comment: That's not the issue, and error is from another part from your code.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad I added a github page so you can see the pushed page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely causing your issue:

```
 .where('email', isEqualTo: loggedInUser!.email)
```

How are you asserting that the user is indeed logged in and promising your compiler that an email is retrievable? This is the explanation of your error.
Refactor your code, in a way to not make it into this block, unless `loggedInUser` is not null.

Comment: I'm trying to check if the task has the same email as loggedInUser's email. Otherwise I don't know how to show the tasks belong to this user.

Comment: Before your query, use `loggedInUser ==null ? CircularProgressIndicator : therestofyourcode`

Comment: I tried what you said but because I use streambuilder I'm getting an error like this: The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'.   This is how I used the code part btw: stream: (loggedInUser == null)
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : _firestore
                .collection('tasks')
                .where('email', isEqualTo: loggedInUser!.email)
                .snapshots(),

Comment: Put what I posted before `StreamBuilder`

Comment: The problem solved but now the circularprogressindicator never stops :( When I reload the code, i saw what I need to see. (I mean cmd + S)